# LaunchMode "singleTop" is ignored when activity is started with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I launch an activity with `startActivityForResult()` and want to prevent multiple instances from being started at the top of activity stack. So I expect `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to do its work, but for some reason the flag gets ignored.

After some investigations I managed to launch only one instance by adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to intent, but I would be grateful if someone could explain me the reason why "singleTop" doesn't work in such case. The code is very simple.

```
// Activity class
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
// multiple instances can be launched without this line
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_DETAILS);

// AndroidManifest.xml
<activity
    android:name=".DetailsActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

How SingleTop work?

let suppose you have current activity stack like

```
A->B->C
```

Now from current activity C, if you start **A** activity which is a singleTop, so in this case system will create a new instance of A  and brings that instance to top. (If specified activity is not on top then new instance will be created)

So stack will look like

```
A->B->C->A
```

Now if you try to open A again then in this case as A on top already, so **NO** new instance will be created. Instead A will receive callback in **onNewIntent()** method

Flag

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
```

it scans from the front of stack to back of stack and if it found instance of specified activity then brings that activity to front.

So in your case if **DetailsActivity** instacne is already present in system then this flag will bring DetailsActivity to front

Comment: Yes, that is what I expect, and that is how it works for usual startActivity(). But in case of starting activity C with startActivityForResult() and launchMode="singleTop" A->B->C stack turns into A->B->C->C and onNewIntent() is not called.

Answer (score 3):

The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` must be ignored in this case because when you launch an `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()` you are basically saying that you want to launch an `Activity` and have the `Activity` return you a result.

If an instance of this `Activity` already exists in the stack (regardless of where it is in the stack), that instance has not been setup to return a result to your `Activity`. It is possible that that instance was launched using `startActivity()` in which case it isn't setup to return a result at all. It could be that it was launched using `startActivityForResult()` from another `Activity`, in which case it is set up to return a result to the `Activity` that launched it, not to your `Activity`.

These 2 things: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `startActivityForResult()` therefore are in conflict.